Problem in port forwarding with keycloak container
I deployed a Keycloak container in my kind cluster using their  Extra Port Mappings instructions. My container runs on the worker node and config seems correct to me:
[gandolf@archlinux ~]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS         PORTS                                           NAMES
07cb9c3ce13d   kindest/node:v1.29.2   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   2 hours ago   Up 5 minutes   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 127.0.0.1:41837->6443/tcp   homosapiens-control-plane
dae7494c1250   kindest/node:v1.29.2   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   2 hours ago   Up 5 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp                          homosapiens-worker

From k9s:
keycloak  ●  quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.2  true  Running  false         1 off:on          0:0     0:0 http:8080 # container on port 8080

and logs:
2024-04-11 04:44:39,968 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Keycloak 24.0.2 on JVM (powered by Quarkus 3.8.3) started in 13.057s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
2024-04-11 04:44:39,969 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile dev activated. 

Despite that, I can't seem to reach it:
[gandolf@archlinux ~]$ curl http://localhost:8080
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

When I explicitly do port forward, it works, but I'm confused why I need to do this. Shouldn't the extra port mappings be handling this?
This doesn't seem to be an issue with other containers like nginx.
